# What do I do if I don't have root access to do a gem install mysql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I run `rake db:create`, I get the notice that I have to run "sudo gem install mysql", but I do not have root access and the tech support is telling me that they cannot do that for me since it is on a shared server.

Is there any work around about this? I do not have the option of changing hosting as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it can't find the MySQL libraries to build the native extension. You can find out where the libs and includes are installed by running

```
mysql_config --libs --include
```

which will produce something like

```
-rdynamic -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lmygcc
-I/usr/local/mysql/include
```

Then with the -L option(location of the mysql libraries) and the -I option(location of the mysql include files) you can install the gem like this

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Obviously the paths for your install will be different, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not root, your gems become installed in your home dir - if you run your application under your username, the gems become loaded from your .gems directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run

```
gem install mysql
```

?

They should get installed in your user's directory. If not, ask your host again. Mine will install any common gem if asked nicely.

Comment: > gem install mysql
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 and /usr/local/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /usr/home/reve18/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb install mysql
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no

Comment: I've asked my really crappy hosting tech support but they are not being very friendly about doing this for me.. any suggestions??

Comment: you could try freezing the gem... http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/1/3/freezing-your-rails-application

Comment: the other way around would be to roll back to rails 2.1, before the mysql gem